# Prevent text from moving in accordian Elementor Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, elementor

by any chance does anyone knows how to prevent text from moving/ rearranging number of lines whenever I open up the accordian container in elementor? I have an accordian type container which open side ways to the right so when the text paragraph appears it will always resize/ moving.

I've tried to follow youtube tutorials but non of them are working, not sure if im searching the wrong keywords or did i missed out something